# Extract all classes from body element of AJAX-ed page and replace current page's body classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am in the process of AJAX-ing a WordPress theme with a persistent music player. Wordpress uses dynamic classes on the `<body>` tag. The basic structure is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body class="unique-class-1 unique-class-2 unique-class-3">
        <div id="site-container">
            <nav class="nav-primary">
                <a href="/other-page-01/">Other Page 01</a>
                <a href="/other-page-02/">Other Page 02</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="site-inner">
                <p>Site Content Here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="music-player"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am currently successfully loading the content of `/other-page-01/`, `/other-page-02/`, etc, using `load('/other-page-01/ #site-container')`. However, I need to extract all `<body>` classes from the AJAX loaded page and replace the current page's `<body>` classes with them dynamically.

Note: Replacing the entire `<body>` element is not an option due to the persistent `<div id="music-player">`. I've tried `jQuery.get()`, but couldn't get it to work.

**How do I extract the `<body>` classes from the AJAX requested page and replace the current page's `<body>` classes with them?**

I am not very familiar with jQuery or Javascript, so the exact code would be extremely helpful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Jeezes `document.body.className`

Comment: Show what you tried, so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @adeneo That won't work, he's looking for the class name from the body element of something he loaded in AJAX, i.e., it's a string.

Comment: @samanime - Oh, didn't notice, most of the time head and body elements will be removed when getting content with ajax, especially when using load() with a selector like that.

Answer (score 1):

My typical solution would have been to tell you to throw the AJAX code in to a jQuery object and then read it out like normal:

```
$(ajaxResult).attr('class');
```

Interestingly though, it appears you can't do this with a `<body>` element.

I'd say the easiest solution (if you have control over the resulting HTML) is to just use some good ol' regex:

```
var matches = ajaxResult.match(/<body.*class=["']([^"']*)["'].*>/),
    classes = matches && matches[1];
```

I say "if you have control over the resulting HTML", because this relies on the HTML being reasonably well formed.

The other method would involve parsing it as a `DOMDocument` and then extracting what you need, but this would take a lot more and is usually overkill in simple cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the body within your returned html to a div with a specific ID, then target that id to get the classes of the body (which is now a div.)

```
modifiedAjaxResult = ajaxResult.replace(/<body/i,'<div id="re_body"')
                               .replace(/<\/body/i,'</div');
$(modifiedAjaxResult).filter("#re_body").attr("class");
```

Of course, if the body has an id, this will conflict with it, so an arbitrary data attribute might be less likely to break.

```
modifiedAjaxResult = ajaxResult.replace(/<body/i,'<div data-re-id="re_body"')
                               .replace(/<\/body/i,'</div');
$(modifiedAjaxResult).filter("[data-re-id=re_body]").attr("class");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N68St/

Of course, to use this method, you'll have to switch to using $.get instead.

```
$.get("/other-page-01/",function(ajaxResult){
    var modifiedAjaxResult = ajaxResult.replace(/<body/i,'<div data-re-id="re_body"')
                                   .replace(/<\/body/i,'</div');
    alert($(modifiedAjaxResult).filter("[data-re-id=re_body]").attr("class"));
    // the following line replicates what `.load` was doing.
    $(someElement).append( $("<div>").html(ajaxResult).find("#site-container") );
});
```